# Hackers Experience Legacy, What is the bit coin market login credentials?

Tags: hacker-experience

I have a feeling that if you find out the bitcoin market's login credentials, you can log anyone's information, that way, you can have virtually unlimited bitcoins.

Answer (score 1):

Hacking the BitCoin market will give you access to a level 10 Miner, and a log of all transactions, for example, selling, buying or logging into an account.

It is all unknown, so you cannot get the Key from the market, and IPs aren't shown either.